# Add button to top right in Bottom Navigation Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I created an app in Android Studio using the Bottom Navigation Activity template.
There is already a top bar with nothing in it.
I would like to put a button in the right of the top bar (not a menu, a button).
How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Please add some XML code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to go ahead and create a menu, but make its sole menu item appear always instead of in the overflow menu.

First create a menu xml file with your button as a menu item, and mark it to be shown always so it won't be put in an overflow menu.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

If you switch to putting an App Bar directly in your layout ([see here](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top), [and here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up)), and your button is global to your whole activity (not just for a specific fragment) you can set this menu on your MaterialToolbar in your layout xml using `app:menu`. Otherwise, you need to set the menu by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in your Activity or Fragment:

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_bar_menu, menu)
        return true
    }
```

To respond to button presses from the menu, you override `onOptionsItemSelected()`:

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> {
                // do something
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

If you want to do this from a Fragment, call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your fragment's `onViewCreated()`, and you can override the same two above functions in your Fragment.